Are some immune cells contagious?
I was wondering if people can transfer immune cells through touch the same way we can transfer harmful bacteria. Is it possible for immune cells from one body to be transferred to another, and might some of those cells be able to survive in the biome of another individual? And is their a correlation between increases in allergies and auto immune diseases, and touch-conservative societies?

Similar to: Share immunity by kissing?.

Specifically from touch - No.
However, there is one natural mechanism for transfer of immune cells between individuals, breast feeding, particularly the early stages when the milk is known as colostrum.
In all mammals the milk contains immune cells as well as a range of antibodies, non-immune cells and various other components that aren't specifically milk1. These components are thought to provide immunity for the infant until its immune system develops enough to provide protection by itself2.
You should note that this doesn't mean that the cow's milk you drink in your coffee contains cow immune cells, because the processing of the milk destroys these. If you drink raw milk, then you will be consuming some cow cells with that, and your gut will destroy the active cells anyway.
There are more complicated medical treatments that can also transfer immune cells - one specifically for immune cell transfer is adoptive transfer, which involves taking cells from the patient or another person and then using these to transfer back to the patient, usually after modification of the immune cells to respond to a particular antigen (often a cancer cell type). You can also do this with non-immune cells, but the practice is used medically for cancer treatment with immune cells.
References:

Smith CW, Goldman AS. The cells of human colostrum. I. In vitro studies of morphology and functions. Pediatr Res. 1968 Mar;2(2):103-9. doi: 10.1203/00006450-196803000-00005. PMID: 4173318.

Hanson LA, Winberg J. Breast milk and defence against infection in the newborn. Arch Dis Child. 1972 Dec;47(256):845-8. doi: 10.1136/adc.47.256.845. PMID: 4567072; PMCID: PMC1648417.


